# ActiveRecord two tables desc order records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have declared has_many :rates in bboy.rb model. Now I want to output all the records from bboys table matching criteria. Which is: Ordering bboy records in descending order based on how many stars they have received for dimension: foundation.

This is where I am at so far in my ActiveRecord ordering query in desc order for dimension: foundation :
@bboys_foundation = Bboy.rates.where(dimension: 'foundation').?

in bboys/index.html.erb:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="?sort=foundation">Foundation</a></li>
     <li><a href="?sort=originality">Originality</a></li>
     <li><a href="?sort=dynamics">Dynamics</a></li>
     <li><a href="?sort=Execution">Execution</a></li>
     <li><a href="?sort=Battle">Battle</a></li>
     <li><a href="?sort=Votes">Votes</a></li>
        </ul>
```

in bboys_controller index method:

```
if params[:sort].present?
    sort_input = ['foundation', 'originality', 'dynamics', 'execution', 'battle', 'votes']
    @foundation = if sort_input[0].include?

    end
    @originality = if sort_input[1].include?

    end
    @dynamics = if sort_input[2].include?

    end
    @execution = if sort_input[3].include?

    end
    @battle = if sort_input[4].include?

    end
    @votes = if sort_input[5].include?

    end
```

db schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140331112614) do

  create_table "bboys", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "crew"
    t.string   "country"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "rates", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "rater_id"
    t.integer  "rateable_id"
    t.string   "rateable_type"
    t.float    "stars",         null: false
    t.string   "dimension"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the controller action. Doesn't seems to be right.

Comment: @ Manoj Monga I want to trigger separate ActiveRecord query for each array item.